# C++: Creating a vector that points to a class object

Tags: c++

I have the following student class, which creates a student, and then allows me to store that student in a students class vector. I want to now have a Courses vector which allows each student to have it's own grouping of courses that they attend. I want these courses to point to the student that owns them so that when a student is removed from the list of students, their courses are also deleted with them. Ideally, I would like to have this courses vector as a private member of the student class, such that these courses can only be accessed/altered when the specific student that owns them is specified.

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"
#include "students.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){
  Students stuList;
  Student* bob = new Student ("Bob" "Jones" 10000909);
  stuList.add(bob); 
  return 0;

}
```

Student h:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>  
class Student {

    public:
    Student::Student(const string & FName, const string & LName, const int ID);

    private:

    string first;
    string last;
    int id;

};
```

students h:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include "student.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Students {

    public:
    Students(); 
    void add(Student & aStudent);

    private:

    vector<Student*> collection;

};
```

I have been thinking of ways to accomplish this for a while now and I am drawing a blank. Any suggestions/tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can put the courses in your student class

Comment: There is no good reason shown here to use pointers. You could change `vector<Student*>` to `vector<Student>`, and get rid of the `new`.

Comment: 1. Create a `Courses` class
  =>  
2. Add a `vector<Student*>` attribute to the `Courses` class
  =>  
3. Add a `vector<Courses*>` attribute to the `Students` class
  =>  
4. Add `add_Course(Course*)` and `remove_Course(Course*)` methods to the `Students` class
  =>  
5. Add `add_Student(Student*)` and `remove_Student(Student*)` methods to the `Courses` class

Comment: @Kovalainen what is the purpose of the `add_Student(Student*)` and `remove_Student (Student*)` in the `Courses` class?

Comment: You said  "I want these courses to point to the student that owns them so that when a student is removed from the list of students, their courses are also deleted with them.", so I figured you wanted a way to add and remove students from the Courses.

Comment: How about using std::map? Map the students to the courses.

Comment: @kvr I haven't actually used the map function before but that could be interesting. I'll look into the documentation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Student class you can add one vector containing the courses owned by the student and additionally one vector for the group of courses attended:

```
class Student {
   ...
   vector<Course*> ownedCourses;
   vector<Course*> attendedCourses;
};
```

Then in your class Courses you will need a vector containing all the attendants of this course:

```
class Course {
    ...
    vector<Student*> attendants;
};
```

If you now remove a stundent from your list, you will also have the earse all courses owned by him from the lists of the other students:

```
vector<Course*> ownedCourses = studentToRemove.getOwnedCourses();
for (const Course* course : ownedCourses)
{  
    vector<Student*> attendants = course->getStudents();
    for(const Student* student : attendants) {
        student->removeAttendedCourse(course);
    }
}
```